# every time i run my code in python it removes the column heading and switch it with number also it adds columns on the left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('DAQ1.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)
print(df)


splitter = np.where(~df[8].isnull())[0]
for i in range(len(splitter)):
    try:
        end = splitter[i+1]
    except:
        end = len(df)
    val = df[8].iloc[splitter[i]]
    df.iloc[splitter[i]:end, 8] = val


splitter = np.where(~df[7].isnull())[0]
for i in range(len(splitter)):
    try:
        end = splitter[i+1]
    except:
        end = len(df)
    val = df[7].iloc[splitter[i]]
    df.iloc[splitter[i]:end, 7] = val
    

splitter = np.where(~df[10].isnull())[0]
for i in range(len(splitter)):
    try:
        end = splitter[i+1]
    except:
        end = len(df)
    val = df[10].iloc[splitter[i]]
    df.iloc[splitter[i]:end, 10] = val
    
print(df)
df['furnace_power'] = df[8]*df[7]*0.52

df['heat_pump_power'] = df[10]*230*0.62

addy1 = df['furnace_power'].sum()
addy2 = df['heat_pump_power'].sum()

print(df)

print("Sum of furnace power: ", addy1)
print("Sum of heat pump power: ", addy2)

df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv')   #(saving the file)
```

[this is the original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3GQc.png)
[this is the file after I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkqyH.png)

Comment: `df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)`. Why are you skipping rows when reading originally?

Comment: i am skipping first row because later on when i multiply it wont let me execute as the first row is heading aka string

Comment: Can you post the csv file in the question? Just the first few lines would do.

Comment: Based on your original screenshot, I think you just want `df = pd.read_csv('DAQ1.csv')`.

Comment: link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkbaCuR1rhYA_y_gTUV0h7ekIyzcunCu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if you use `header=None` then it adds header as first row and you have numbers as headers and you have to use `skiprows=1`. Why not `to_csv('DAQ1.csv')` ? And if you want to skip indexes then use `index=False`

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `header=None` then it treats first row (with headers) as normal row and you have numbers instead of headers. And you have to skip first row because there are headers.

Simply skip arguments

```
df = pd.read_csv('DAQ1.csv')
```

If you want save without indexes then skip them.

```
df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)
```

---

Doc: [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example.

I use `io.StringIO` only to create example file at start.

```
import pandas as pd

# create example file in memory
import io
text = '''A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
'''
file_object = io.StringIO(text)

# read with headers
df = pd.read_csv(file_object)

print(df)

# save without index
df = df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)

# read again to check index
df = pd.read_csv('DAQ1.csv')

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! I tried doing this but it is giving me following error. 

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: `index` has to be in `to_csv` (for writing), not `read_csv` (for reading)

Comment: how do i defined to_csv?? for me it say it is undefined!! I tried both below

df = df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)
df = to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)

Comment: I don't get it. Did you read my answer ? There is `df.to_csv(...)` . And in your question you have also `df.to_csv(...)` then why do you use `df = to_csv(...)`

Comment: i am saying that i tried both methods and it still doesn't work. 'df = df.to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)' and also tried 'df = to_csv('DAQ1.csv', index=False)' it says 'to_csv' undefined

Comment: if you will try both at the same time then you will always get error because you run `df = to_csv(...)` which makes problem - you have to remove `df = to_csv(...)` to remove error. You have to run ONLY `df.to_csv(...)`. BTW: you don't need to use `df = ` when you run `df.to_csv(..)`

Comment: BTW: you don't need to use `df =` when you run `df.to_csv(...)` because `df.to_csv(...)` returns `None` and you get `df = None`